# Django: Many-to-One Relationships

Tags: django, django-models

Here is the code that I would like to work in setting up a couple of models:

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length = 2)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    y = models.CharField(max_length = 2, default = a.x)
```

However, when I run `python manage.py syncdb`, it tells me that that ForeignKey object a has no attribute x.  I have searched through the Django documentation and so far have been unable to find my answer.  Hopefully the meaning of the code is clear.  How do I actually go about implementing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a totally unrelated question, how does stackoverflow automatically color the code?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put variables in a field's default attribute - it has to be either a constant, or a callable.

If you really need to do this, I guess one way would be to do it in `__init__`:

```
class B(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.a and not self.b:
            self.b == self.a.x
```

but I must say I can't see why you'd want to, as you're just copying a value that is already directly accessible via `a.x`.

Comment: In my particular case 'A' represents a user and 'B' represents a post.  'x' is a field that a user can *optionally* fill out, but I don't want to require them to fill it out.  However, if they want to make a post, I am requiring them to fill in this field for the particular post, in  which case, *if* they've filled this field out for their user profile, I want it to be the default value for the choice.

Given this, from a design standpoint, do you think it is a good idea to use the code you've provided?

Comment: This is probably a separate question, but I'd say that your explanation makes sense and the charfield/foreign key is the correct structure; *however* the default doesn't belong on the model at all, but in the form you use to create the post.

Answer (score 0):

To define a many-to-one relationship, you have to use `django.db.models.ForeignKey.`

```
a= models.ForeignKey(A)
```

Comment: Sorry about that.  That was actually a typo of mine.  I'll edit the post right away.